# How to define React Class/Function components in TypeScript (With typechecking)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components

How to define React Class/Function components in TypeScript and have working typechecking? I not found any full article about how to do it properly.

I am able to define `Props` and `State` interface, but I dont know how to define `defaultProps`, `defaultState`, etc...

Can someone help me (and others) out with some good style? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For a much simpler structure you could go from this:

```
import * as React from "react";

const App = ({ value = 'Hello World' }: { value: string }) => (
  <div>
     <h1>{value}</h1>
  </div>
 )

export default App
```

Where `{ value = 'Hello World' }` is your default props and `{ value: string }` is your typechecking

Here's cheatsheet guide that could help you with React + Typescript:
https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet

Answer (score 0):

That's quite easy. You can still do it the old way. You can still declare it outside of your `function`, like with this example `App.defaultProps`:

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export interface CatProps {
  catName: string;
  eyeColor: string;
  age: string;
}

export default function App(props: CatProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.catName} Cat, Eye Color: {props.eyeColor}, Age: {props.age}
    </div>
  );
}

App.defaultProps = {
  catName: "Sandy",
  eyeColor: "deepblue",
  age: "120"
};
```

Working sample: [Try it](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-jepsen-qge6e%60)

Mess around a little bit, and change the `defaultProps` values.

**Default State**:

Using the example from above, you can define a `defaultState`, simply doing:

```
const [catName, setCatName] = useState('Sandy'); // define a defaultState value inside useState hook
```

Comment: But if I do so, I am not getting right typechecking right?